# Vue.js catch json response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some problems with catching message with my Vue app. I'm using Vuexy admin template and in one file is defined how they return error message.
So Code looks like this:

```
module.exports = function settle(resolve, reject, response) {
  var validateStatus = response.config.validateStatus;
  if (!validateStatus || validateStatus(response.status)) {
    resolve(response);
  } else {
    console.log(response.data)
    reject(createError(
      'Request failed with status code ' + response.status,
      response.config,
      null,
      response.request,
      response
    ));
  }
};
```

And It's returning that message with status code, but as you see I'm trying to console.log response.data, and I'm getting info that I need. Console log looks like

```
{"response":false,"status":400,"message":"Provided details are not correct!"}
```

But when I try to catch message like response.data.message I'm receiving that message is undefined, any ideas why?
!=
BTW: response.status is getting status from HTTP response, not from json status code!

Comment: Can you change `console.log(response.data)` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2))`,  try again and show what you got?

Comment: Well in that case I have "{\"response\":false,\"status\":400,\"message\":\"Provided details are not correct!\"}"

Comment: What `createError` function do? Maybe it mutates `response`?